# Instagram user_id for facebook graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, graph, instagram

The thing seems very stupid but instagram hashtag search endpoint requires user_id param.
How do i get that user_id from login or from my account ?

I've been searching for it for very long time and nothing seems to works as Graph API Explorer always returns `error code 100` with message:

> "(#100) Param user_id is not a valid Instagram User ID"

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user: _“Represents an Instagram Business Account or an Instagram Creator Account.”_ - if you don’t have an account that is of either of these two types, then you can not use the new Instagram API to begin with.

Comment: i do have one, but don't know where can i find it's ID.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#5--get-the-page-s-instagram-business-account